# Azure/Kudu update python PATH from 2.7 to 3.6

Tags: django, python-3.x, azure, kudu

I have tried all day to publish my Django Project from Visual Studio and I think I have nailed down the problem. When it automatically created the environment, it installed Python 2.7. I am using Django 2.2+, which only runs on Python 3+.

**Python 3.6 path:**

```
D:\home\python364x64>
```

I can get the environment to use 3.6 for a session but I can't work out how to make the change permanent from either the Kudu Powershell or the Azure portal.

I am clearly missing something very simple but none of the documentation covers this problem.

This is also the web.config file. I dont know if it helps at all so I'll add it as it is better to have too much info than not enough:

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="handler.fcgi" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts\pip3.exe" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Static Files" stopProcessing="true">
          <conditions>
            <add input="true" pattern="false" />
          </conditions>
        </rule>
        <rule name="Configure Python" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/static/.*" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.fcgi/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts\pip3.exe"
                  arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\runserver.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="D:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()"/>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\homepython364x64\Scripts"/>
    <add key="WSGI_LOG" value="D:\home\LogFiles\wfastcgi.log"/>
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="FTAData.settings" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
           scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts\pip3.exe"
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

applicationHost.xtd:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"> 
  <system.webServer> 
    <runtime xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
      <environmentVariables xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <add name="PATH" value="D:\home\python364x64\Scripts" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing" />    
      </environmentVariables>
    </runtime> 
  </system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

**Edit:**
I forgot to mention, I have ran my requirements file in the Python3.6 folder and it went through perfectly. Only error message I got was the PATH variable.

On top of that, I have got the initial landing page and continuous delivery working perfectly as well (tested by changing text on the default landing page, saving and refreshing in browser)

Also, this is what shows up in Kudu under PATH:

```
D:\home\site\deployments\tools
D:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\82.10503.3890\bin\Scripts
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin
D:\Program Files\Git\cmd
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.1\Framework\v4.0
D:\Program Files\Git\bin
D:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin
D:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin
D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.10.8
C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1FTAData\AppData\npm
D:\Program Files (x86)\bower\1.7.9
D:\Program Files (x86)\grunt\0.1.13
D:\Program Files (x86)\gulp\3.9.0.1
D:\Program Files (x86)\funcpack\1.0.0
D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\6.9.1
D:\Windows\system32
D:\Windows
D:\Windows\System32\Wbem
D:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
D:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet
D:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd
D:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6
D:\Python27
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need install the python with the version, you could go to the extension or install the packages.

Go to your extension under azure app, choose add extension and choose the version you want. Cause you already have the session path, I think you have installed the python. You could go directly to set the web.config.

[image]

Yo could set the HttpPlatform (recommended) or FastCGI, the below is a HttpPlatform sample.

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="D:\home\Python361x64\python.exe"
                  arguments="D:\home\site\wwwroot\runserver.py --port %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
                  stdoutLogEnabled="true"
                  stdoutLogFile="D:\home\LogFiles\python.log"
                  startupTimeLimit="60"
                  processesPerApplication="16">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="SERVER_PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

For more details, you could refer to the official doc:[set up a Python environment on Azure App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2019).

**Update:** If the web.config way didn't work, you could go to the Configuration under you Azure App-> Path mappings->+ New handler

extension : `fastCgi`

processor: `D:\home\python364x64\python.exe`

arguments: `D:\home\python364x64\wfastcgi.py`

SAve your settings.

[image]

Restart your app and go to your app kudu, check if the settings work.

[image]

Comment: Hello George. You are right, I've installed the correct virsion of Python. I've added that section of code before (and changed python361x64 to python364x64) as well as read the official docs. This is the first time I've tried to run a Python framework on a live server so I think I'm just missing something really obvious.

Comment: @Jordan Lashmar, I have updated my answer, please check it.

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much George. Now I am getting a different error: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." but that has changed the Python version the server is using :D